# String containing digits and the letter 'M' cannot be printed. Why?

Tags: java, string, maven-2, jvm

I tried to print to console string composed of digits and capitalized M. It was like:

```
System.out.println("blah");
System.out.println("123M");
System.out.println("blah blah");
```

and the result was

```
blah
blah blah
```

So `println("123M")` wasn't even executed as there is no empty line between two others. Digits number and combination doesn't matter, but if there will be any letter before 'M' or non-whitespace character following 'M', string will be printed.

Tried on java 1.7.0_03-b05 and two other (don't know version).
Thank you for any clues.

**Update:**
Problem appears in maven project.

Below is the screenshot for that:

[image]

**Another update:**

After [Charlee Chitsuk](/users/813999/charlee-chitsuk)'s post about pom I changed mine to:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>javaapplication4.JavaApplication4</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

and after `mvn clean compile assembly:single` I finally received properly working jar.
Why it wasn't working with exec-maven-plugin will remain a mystery to me.

Comment: are you sure its not working??? i just checked its working for me...

Comment: Did you forget to re-compile it after you added in the second line?

Comment: I asked three people at work to try and they confirmed the problem.

Comment: @RafałKuliński Clean the project and rebuild it. then run it.

Comment: I'm confused by the downvotes.  This seems like a legitimate question, properly stated.

Comment: Change "blah" to "something_relevant" and see if you see something relevant!

Comment: It appeared in different project, where string was changed, appended, splitted and so on. So I started the second one to isolate the problem. The code above is the simplest one to see the idea (blah's were added later to be sure there is no new line). The project was cleaned and rebuilded after each change.

Comment: Try to put "123M" in string and print it

Comment: Please include an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) that reliably reproduces the problem for you. Without one, the question is unanswerable.

Comment: I tried. This makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

> I wrote this class and got one clue. It fails only in Maven project.

In that case it is almost certain that what you're running isn't the code you think you're running. That's the only plausible explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I've been noticed that you're using the `org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec` to execute your `JavaApplication4.java`. Then I guess that your `pom.xml` may look like

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <executable>java</executable>
      <arguments>
        <argument>-classpath</argument>
        <!-- automatically creates the classpath using all project dependencies,
             also adding the project build directory -->
        <classpath/>
        <argument>javaapplication4.JavaApplication4</argument>
        ...
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

The `build and clean` by using `Eclipse Menu` is totally different from `mvn clean install`. Normally I'using the following step for working with Maven in Eclipse: -

1. Right Click at the project select `Run As ----> Maven clean`
2. Right Click at the project select `Run As ----> Maven test` or `Run As ----> Maven install`

I would like to inform you to review the `org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin` configuration and try to clean the project by using the step 1. Then run your class again.

I hope this may help.

Comment: I use NetBeans and to be sure I used maven custom goals and then typed `clean install`. That did't help, but take a look on my first post update.